# Can you farm leaves?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Can I repeatedly shear tree leaves to get unlimited saplings?

If so, would this work on Silverleaf Trees?

Just to clarify, I was attempting at shearing leaves to get the leaf block AND a sapling, then planning on placing the collected leaf block back down, and repeating. Primarily to get Silverleaf Saplings.

Comment: Can you clarify? You can only shear as many leaves as there are on the trees...

Comment: You're looking for a Thaumatic Grafter with Repair II on it.

Comment: Yes, no, and no. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can farm leaves from trees, either breaking them for the chance of producing a [sapling](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Saplings) or using [shears](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shears) or a [Silk-Touch-enchanted](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchant#Enchantments) tool to collect the leaf block. But you can't do this repeatedly for the same tree as leaves do not grow back. You will have to grow a new tree to get more leaves.

As for [Silverwood trees](http://ftbwiki.org/Silverwood_Tree), you can break their leaves for a small chance at getting a sapling (on average around 1 per tree). Harvesting the leaves with shears will just give you the leaf block, without any chance at a sapling. In addition, items/enchantments designed to increase item yield or chance of item drop, like [Fortune](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchant#Enchantments) or a [grafter](http://ftbwiki.org/Grafter), do not appear to work on Silverwood trees.

**Note:** Apparently, collecting leaves with a Silk-Touch-enchanted tool can [sometimes give you both the leaf block *and* a sapling](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shears#Trivia). It's not clear if this is a bug or intentional, but I imagine this only works on vanilla trees.

Comment: I sometimes get saplings shearing vanilla trees too, so its not just silk touch. The question is if I can place the leaves back down and CONTINUE to shear them for more saplings.

Comment: @Ender Are you very sure it's from the same block? Once you shear some leaves there are going to be disconnected blocks that will decay on their own. Might you have sheared a leaf block that just had a sapling sitting on top of it from a different block decaying, or coincidentally sheared a leaf at the same time a nearby block decayed into a sapling?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I wouldn't swear my life on it.

Answer (score 1):

The way Minecraft stores data is in the block itself. Not when you break it. When the leaf is first spawned by the world generation, the data at that point controls whether or not the leaf drops a sapling. It is not decided when the block is broken which is a common misconception.

So, when the block is broken with shears/silk touch, the data is removed BUT will not drop a sapling because Minecraft (Mojang) does not want you getting infinite saplings with this. When you place the leaf back down, it will generate whether or not to drop a sapling or not.

Fortune on axes runs its own randomizer to determine how many leaves the block should drop but ALSO removes the data currently in the block, like silk touch.

Comment: can you provide some form of source to back this up?

Comment: Do I really have to download MC Coder Pack just to decompile and then show code that most people won't understand? The stuff I'm talking about isn't on the wiki.

Comment: Not neccesarily, but you may have noticed that nobody upvoted this answer, and that's likely because you have no source. Some of us spend days on a single answer or question, slowly improving it over time, until it reaches the quality we wish it to be. It all depends on your ambition. Nobody is forcing you to do anything, least of all me.

Comment: This is false. The only data stored in leaves are "decayable " and "checkDecay", both of which are related to the block decaying. The method dropBlockAsItemWithChance, which is run when a block is destroyed contains the following code, cut short so this fits in a comment

    int i = this.getSaplingDropChance();
    if(world.random.nextInt(i){
        spawnAsEntity(worldIn, pos, new 
  
  
     ItemStack(Item.getItemFrommBlock(Blocks.SAPLING),1,this.damageDropped(state))):
    }

In summary, you're wrong

Comment: I don't know why the code formatting broke